# What is the use of printStackTrace() method in Java?

Tags: java, exception, printstacktrace

I am going through a socket program. In it, `printStackTrace` is called on the `IOException` object in the catch block.
What does `printStackTrace()` actually do?

```
catch(IOException ioe)
{
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am unaware of its purpose. What is it used for?

Comment: One of the most powerful features in modern IDE's is the ability to look up documentation (called javadoc) for a given Java method.  In Eclipse it is Shift-F2 when the cursor is placed on the printStackTrace method name.

Comment: Sounds like you're new to Java. Here's something to read: http://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns

Comment: You can also read the code of the printStackTrace() to see exactly what it does and how it does it.

Comment: What a cool functionality! i dont know it before. But i guess it will be better if i can make the fonts displayed bigger, just like the real web browser.@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: @MarkZar Eclipse by default use an internal browser.  You can set it to use the system browser, which use your normal browser with its normal settings.

Comment: I often see this pattern inside catch blocks:
```e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(1);
```
Here I want to ask the same question as the OP, but in a different vein: What exactly is the purpose of this? Won't the JRE automatically print the stacktrace and exit, when the exception is thrown?  I.e., there isn't really very much "Exception Handling" going on here, right??

Comment: It's also generally a [very bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7469316/113632), as it suppresses the exception - unfortunately it's what Eclipse and other IDEs often auto-suggest as the body for the catch block, so it's used *far* more often than it should be.

Comment: And now [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info) will [warn you about it](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/CatchAndPrintStackTrace) :)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

It's a method on `Exception` instances that [prints the stack trace of the instance to `System.err`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()).

It's a very simple, but very useful tool for diagnosing an exceptions. It tells you what happened and where in the code this happened.

Here's an example of how it might be used in practice:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (SomeException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that in "serious production code" you usually don't want to do this, for various reasons (such as `System.out` being less useful and not thread safe). In those cases you usually use some log framework that provides the same (or very similar) output using a command like `log.error("Error during frobnication", e);`.

Comment: And thanks to checked exceptions it's probably the #1 content of `catch` blocks :-)

Comment: @Joey Or `throw new RuntimeException(e)`

Comment: however it is considered bad practice as it is not threadsafe. Use the logger statement and include it there.

Answer (score 46):

I was kind of curious about this too, so I just put together a little sample code where you can see what it is doing:

```
try {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

try {
    throw new IOException();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.exit(0);
```

**Calling `println(e)`:**

> `java.lang.NullPointerException`

**Calling `e.printStackTrace()`:**

> ```
> java.io.IOException
>       at package.Test.main(Test.java:74)
> ```

Comment: This is normal, with the 1st one you call the toString() of the error, and in the 2nd you ask to print all the stackTrace from the error. That's 2 différents things.

Comment: `System.err.println(e);` will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 14):

It helps to trace the exception. For example you are writing some methods in your program and one of your methods causes bug. Then printstack will help you to identify which method causes the bug. Stack will help like this:

First your main method will be called and inserted to stack, then the second method will be called and inserted to the stack in LIFO order and if any error occurs somewhere inside any method then this stack will help to identify that method.

Answer (score 11):

`printStackTrace()` helps the programmer to understand where the actual problem occurred. `printStacktrace()` is a method of the class `Throwable` of `java.lang` package. It prints several lines in the output console. 
The first line consists of several strings. It contains the name of the Throwable sub-class & the package information. 
From second line onwards, it describes the error position/line number beginning with `at`.

The last line always describes the destination affected by the error/exception. The second last line informs us about the next line in the stack where the control goes after getting transfer from the line number described in the last line. The errors/exceptions represents the output in the form a stack, which were fed into the stack by `fillInStackTrace()` method of `Throwable` class, which itself fills in the program control transfer details into the execution stack. The lines starting with `at`, are nothing but the values of the execution stack. 
In this way the programmer can understand where in code the actual problem is.

Along with the `printStackTrace()` method, it's a good idea to use `e.getmessage()`.

Answer (score 6):

`printStackTrace()` prints the locations where the exception occurred in the source code, thus allowing the author who wrote the program to see what went wrong. But since it shows problems in the source code, the user(s) who may or may not have any coding experience may not be able to understand what went wrong, so if the program allows the user to send error messages to the authors, the users may not be able to give good data on what went wrong.

You should consider the `Logger.getLogger()` method, it offers a better exception handling (logging) facility, and besides `printStackTrace()` without arguments is considered to be obsolete and should ONLY be used for debugging purposes, not for user display.

Answer (score 2):

The `printStackTrace()` helps the programmer understand where the actual problem occurred.  The `printStackTrace()` method is a member of the class `Throwable` in the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 2):

`printStackTrace` is a method of the `Throwable` class. This method displays error message in the console; where we are getting the exception in the source code. These methods can be used with catch block and they describe:

1. Name of the exception.
2. Description of the exception.
3. Location of the exception in the source code.

The three methods which describe the exception on the console (in which printStackTrace is one of them) are:

1. `printStackTrace()`
2. `toString()`
3. `getMessage()`

Example:

```
public class BabluGope {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(10/0);
         } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();   
             // System.err.println(e.toString());
             //System.err.println(e.getMessage());  
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

printStackTrace() helps the programmer to understand where the actual problem occurred. It helps to trace the exception.
it is printStackTrace() method of Throwable class inherited by every exception class. This method prints the same message of e object and also the line number where the exception occurred.

The following is an another example of print stack of the Exception in Java.

```
public class Demo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         ExceptionFunc();
      } catch(Throwable e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public static void ExceptionFunc() throws Throwable {
      Throwable t = new Throwable("This is new Exception in Java...");

      StackTraceElement[] trace = new StackTraceElement[] {
         new StackTraceElement("ClassName","methodName","fileName",5)
      };
      t.setStackTrace(trace);
      throw t;
   }
}
```

java.lang.Throwable: This is new Exception in Java...
    at ClassName.methodName(fileName:5)

Answer (score 0):

**What is the use of e.printStackTrace() method in Java?**

Well, the purpose of using this method `e.printStackTrace();` is to see what exactly wrong is.

For example, we want to handle an exception. Let's have a look at the following Example.

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 12;
    int b = 2;

    try {
       int result = a / (b - 2);
       System.out.println(result);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I've used method `e.printStackTrace();` in order to show exactly what is wrong.

In the output, we can see the following result.

```
Error: / by zero

java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

  at Main.main(Main.java:10)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```