# FIleNotFoundException - illegal start of expression - NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I get the following error message 'llegal start of expression' at line

> throws FileNotFoundException

I have done some research but wasn't able to fix it. Can you help? Many thanks, zan

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class training{
        public static void main(String[]args){

            throws FileNotFoundException{

            Scanner diskScanner = new Scanner(new File("occupancy"));

            out.println("Room\tGuests");

            for(int roomNum = 0; roomNum < 10; roomNum ++){
                out.print(roomNum);
                out.print("\t");
                out.println(diskScanner.nextInt());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Declare that main can throw that exception?  Or are you looking for a try-catch syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have a curly brace before the throws keyword :

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {
                                     ^-- no curly brace
```

Note that a class should always start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

Improper use of `throws`.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
 ..
}
```

It is better to use try..catch

```
public static void main(String[]args) 
    {
      try
       {
        ..
       }catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
          //
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code with the try/catch block does basically the same thing, except it's longer, and exits with 0 (success) rather than 1 (error). I would argue that the code with the throws clause is better.

Comment: @JBNizet Agree with current code snippet but what happen when method contain other statements? In OP post, he/she has to handle **NoSuchElementException** too.

Comment: He could also add this exception to the throws clause. There is no need to catch an exception if it's just to print its stack trace and exit.

Comment: Please, *please*, do not call `printStackTrace` and continue as if nothing happened: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7469316/238421, http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong. Check your source and/or the language specification.