# java serialization working unexpectedly?

Tags: java, serialization

Hi If a class cannot implement serializable interface and if we try to serialize it, we should get a `NotSerializableException.` Here I am not getting it. The `Cat` class doesn't implement `Serializable` and I try to serialize it. Compiled and run fine why?

```
 import java.io.*;
 class Cat{}
 class MyTest{
 public static void main(String a[]){
    Cat c = new Cat();
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(c);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        c =  (Cat)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
}
}
```

Comment: how do you know you are not getting error

Comment: Exactly. With that code, you can't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is throwing exceptions, you are just swallowing them with

```
catch(Exception e){e.getMessage();}
```

which just calls a method that returns a String, it doesn't log anything.

Use

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice.... Is there any other way?

Comment: @JNL Of course. The methods of `Exception` give you all sorts of options: get the error message, get the stack trace, and you can override or add and use your own.