# What does this error in my Logcat mean

Tags: android, performance, android-logcat

I am having problem to understand the error in my Logcat,can you help me please how can i fixed this.

```
    04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error   occured while executing doInBackground()
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:118)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:1)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report crashs to logcat you should use [`Log.d/v/etc(TAG, Message, Throwable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) not `e.printStackTrace()`.

---

Anyway, your code crashs because `e.getMessage()` could be null and Log don't accept `null` as message.

So change your line to

```
Log.e("MY_APP_error!", "Error!", e);
```

Comment: what does the printStacktrace()?i thought it will report eror

Comment: Yes, but while in console applications it could be OK in android it's not. It would be too long for a comment so i found this answer for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

The message you put in `Log` is null. That is written right here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:231)
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:118)
```

Check what you are using in `Log` message.

Comment: More help: Line 118 of adduser.java

Comment: this is what i put in Line 118 adduser.java  Log.e("MY_APP_error!", e.getMessage()); this is inside my catch(IOException e)

Comment: use e.printStacktrace(); instead of logging e.getMessage()

Comment: e.printStackTrace() is indeed a better way to see, what happened.

Answer (score 1):

As your logcat says

```
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
04-06 08:17:54.738: E/AndroidRuntime(4491):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
```

You have a NullPointerException, probably you call Log.e() and pass a null value in a variable.