# Scheduled task never throws exceptions

Tags: java, error-handling, stack-trace, runnable, runtimeexception

This question can be seen as a whole in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353558/printstacktrace-in-a-finished-product-when-and-why). Though the linked post explains this issue, you should not think of it as a duplicate: it asks a different question and has an accepted answer for this different question.

Though the question can be read in the other post, I'll explain it here as well:

I'm developing a snake-like game that can be played with AIs, and is intended for that purpose. All such AIs should extend an abstract class called `SnakeLogic`. All such AIs should also reside in their standalone .jar archives in a specific folder, from where the main program can find them and list them using classloaders.

The user can then choose one of his/her AIs from a list, should all stars fall in line, and play a game with this AI.

Now, I have a method in my main program that gets the next move from the AI like so:

```
public void startGame(int speed) {        
    gameInterface.showWindow();
    Runnable moveCmd = () -> {
        try {

            for (Player player : snakeGame.getPlayers()) {
                if (player.isDead()) {
                    continue;
                }

                String move = player.getLogicHandler().getMove();

                Direction direction = Direction.directionFromString(move);
                snakeGame.makeMove(player, direction);
            }

            gameInterface.getFrame().repaint();
            snakeGame.wait(speed);

            if (snakeGame.gameOver()) {
                stopGame();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            stopGame();
        }
    };

    /* moveSchedule is an instance of ScheduledExecutorService */
    moveSchedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(moveCmd, 1000, speed, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);        
}
```

I'm not going to get too involved with the code above. I'd like to draw your attention to the try-catch statement, however. As you can see I print the stacktrace and end the game, should an exception occur somewhere during the execution of the `moveCmd` runnable. If I don't print the stacktrace like this, or if I remove the try-catch entirely, I never get any errors in the case of a runtime exception during the execution of that block. Why? Is it because it's wrapped inside a runnable? Note also that the line `snakeGame.makeMove(player, direction);` doesn't call any code in the main program; `snakeGame` is an instance of a `SnakeLogic`, which resides in an external .jar.

Why don't I get any errors if I remove the try-catch? By errors I mean runtime errors.

Comment: Looks a bit like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546193/how-to-catch-an-exception-from-a-thread

Comment: Why don't I get any errors if I remove the try-catch? you mean during runtime or compile time?

Comment: @Matt That question involves `Thread`s, my question doesn't.

Comment: @sol4me during runtime. Sorry, I had tagged this as a runtimeexception question but didn't mention it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this code in FutureTask:

```
 try {
            runner = Thread.currentThread();
            if (getState() == RUNNING)
                callable.call(); // don't set result
            runner = null;
            return compareAndSetState(RUNNING, 0);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            innerSetException(ex);
            return false;
        }
```

So it is catching the exception and setting it to return only on performing Callable.get()

Comment: Is there a way of aquiring the exception, or telling it to throw it like a normal good-behaving program, apart from how I did it?

Comment: You can either surround as you did, everything with a Try-Catch in the run() method or use a Callable which can throw exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html