# Exceptions and jumbled output in each execution, can someone pls clarify this?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, execution

I was experimenting something with exceptions in java and during execution found something strange. The following is the code I was trying with,

```
public class Client
{
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public static void main(String a[]) 
    {
        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First Exception");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SOP 1 ");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Second Exception");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("SOP 2");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Thried Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

I was getting the following jumbled output in each execution (though mostly I was getting the Result 1, which is the expected o/p according to me). I was using Eclipse IDE for the execution. Couldn't find a reason for this, can someone pls clarify why the output is coming jumbled like this ?

```
(Result 1)---------------------------------------------------------------------

SOP 1 
SOP 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Thried Exception
    at client.main(client.java:13)

(Result 2)---------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Thried Exception
    at client.main(client.java:13)
SOP 1 
SOP 2

(Result 3)---------------------------------------------------------------------

Exception in thread "main" SOP 1 
SOP 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Thried Exception
    at client.main(client.java:13)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice