# Retrieving all records from a atable using java JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

I am trying to write a simple query using JPQ to retrieve all the rows in a table. I believe I have set up my entity up correctly as well as my persistence unit as the tables were successfully created on deployment of the module. My issue is that when I try to retrieve anything from the table it does not work.

The code in my EJB to retrieve the rows looks like this:

```
@Override
public List<Car> getAllCars() throws Exception 
{        
    return entityManager.createNamedQuery(Car.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME).getResultList();
}
```

The code that calls that looks like this:

```
    try
    {/*
        String[] test = new String[7];
        test[0] = "test";
        test[1] = "test";
        test[2] = "test";
        test[3] = "test";
        test[4] = "test";
        test[5] = "test";
        test[6] = "test";
        main.getCarScreen().getModel().addRow(test);
        System.out.println("test");*/

        List<Car> cars = carRepo.getAllCars();
        for(Car car : cars)
        {//"VIN", "Model Number", "Model Name", "Make", "Thumbnail", "Description", "URL"
            String[] data = new String[7];
            data[0] = car.getVIN();
            data[1] = car.getModelNo();
            data[2] = car.getModel();
            data[3] = car.getMake();
            data[4] = car.getThumbnail();
            data[5] = car.getDesc();
            data[6] = car.getPrevURL();
            main.getCarScreen().getModel().addRow(data);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        main.getCarScreen().outputAddError(ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("failed");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

I have tested and I know that the `carRepo.getAllCars();` is the bit that is failing.
The result of the `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` is just a simple: **null**

The beginning of my car entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Car.GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME, query = "SELECT c FROM Car AS c")})
public class Car implements Serializable
{
    public static final String GET_ALL_QUERY_NAME = "Car.getAll";
```

I that there is data in the table:
[image]

The fact that the exception message is a simple **null** makes me believe that the code is working but there is nothing to retrieve in the table. When I check the table data however my test data is still there.

Can anyone see why this is failing to retrieve any rows?

[UPDATE]

So I changed the carRepo.getAllCars() to ex.printStackTrace(); and it is indeed a null pointer exception. Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at CarSales.CarSales.displayAllCars(CarSales.java:55)
at CarSales.CarSales.run(CarSales.java:35)
at CarSales.Main.main(Main.java:18)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.launch(AppClientFacade.java:183)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientGroupFacade.main(AppClientGroupFacade.java:65)
```

CarSales.java:55 is the line

```
List<Car> cars = carRepo.getAllCars()
```

I am pretty new to JPQL and I have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Stop catching Exception. Or at least replace `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` by `ex.printStackTrace();`. You probably have a NullPointerException, and the stack trace will tell you where it happens.

Comment: There is nothing JPQL specific here, your error is pure java. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it -  `carRepo` is not set.

Comment: i suggest not to use `ex.printStackTrace();` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice here you can read about it more. I assume your problem is solved by pointing out that your carRepo is null?