# Alternative to e.printStackTrace() and an example code will be helpful

Tags: java, printstacktrace

I have used `e.printStackTrace` in one of my Java applications. However, I read in some forum that we should avoid using `printStackTrace()`. Could somebody explain to me why I should avoid using `e.printStackTrace()` and what are the alternatives to it?
Please share the piece of code for an alternative to e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is exception.printStackTrace() considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

Loggers should be used instead of printing the whole stack trace on stream.
e.printStackTrace() prints a Throwable and its stack trace to stream which could inadvertently expose sensitive information.

Loggers should be used instead to print Throwables, as they have many advantages.

more info :
https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/2017/A3_2017-Sensitive_Data_Exposure.html

Answer (score 2):

I usually log errors this way:

```
} catch (IOException ex) {
  log.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

If you use lombok, you can add logger to your class with `@Log` annotation on class.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid it because it is better to use a logger like [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), so that you can write logs in a file & manage the logging better.

Indeed, the method

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

is used to print the stack of the exception directly in the console, and that (for a production application) is bad.